# how to show list view in my urls based on string not integer in django

Tags: django

this is my model where I have people class where every person in this people class lives in a zone this is my people class and zone class

```
class Zones(models.Model):
    zone_name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.zone_name

class People(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    address = models.TextField()
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    national_number = models.CharField(max_length=14)
    no_of_members = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=False, blank=False)
    zone = models.ForeignKey(Zones, null=False, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name
```

and how I want to show them the in the route /zone will be list of my zones, and when the user click on any of those zone I want him to see list of people who are in this zone

here is my views

```
class PeopleView(ListView):
    model = People
    template_name = "people.html"
    context_object_name = 'people_list'


class ZoneView(ListView):
    model = Zones
    template_name = "zones.html"
    context_object_name = 'zones_list'

class PeopleDetailView(DetailView):
    model = People
    template_name = "people_detail.html"
```

and here is my urls

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('people/', PeopleView.as_view(), name='people'),
    path('zone/', ZoneView.as_view(), name='zone'),
    path('zone/<int:pk>/', PeopleDetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
]
```

and here is my html template for zone

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Zones List</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Zones List</h1>
    <ul>
        {% for zone in zones_list %}
            <a href="#"><li>{{ zone }}</li></a>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have messed views and urls: zone is linked to peopledetailview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your url path to

```
...
 path('zone/<str:zone_name>/', PeopleView.as_view(), name='detail'),
...
```

And update your `PeopleView` with the following:

```
class PeopleView(ListView):
    model = People
    template_name = "people.html"
    context_object_name = 'people_list'

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if 'zone_name' in self.kwargs:
            return  People.objects.filter(zone__zone_name=self.kwargs ['zone_name'])
        return super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs)
```